# Boltzmann machines - motivation for the energy function

Tags: statistics, computer-science, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, machine-learning

I've been studying [Boltzmann machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine) lately and was wondering if anyone could give me a "high-level" explanation or motivation for the energy function used:

$$E = -\sum_{i<j} w_{ij} \, s_i \, s_j - \sum_i \theta_i \, s_i$$

where:

- $w_{ij}$ is the connection strength between unit $j$ and unit $i$,
- $s_i$ is the state, $s_i \in \{0,1\}$, of unit $i$.
- $\theta_i$ is the threshold of unit $i$

Why do we use this particular function? What is the motivation? Is it modelled after some real world phenomena? Could we use a different one?

Comment: Simplest possible function that links $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Is this the only motivation?

Comment: If a linear approximation works well enough...

Comment: In his [lecture](https://class.coursera.org/neuralnets-2012-001/lecture/125) (01:31) on Hopfield nets with hidden units, Hinton says that "our current model of the world" is encoded in the the energy function. That makes me think that there's more to it.

Comment: It's possible that by the "encoding" he meant the weight values $w_{ij}$ that we have learned.

Comment: I would still be grateful if someone could elaborate on this though!